# ActionController::UnknownFormat in controller rspec after rails 4 upgrade

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec-rails

I have been stuck on this issue for a day. This is how the controller looks like:

```
class HarvestSchedulesController < ApplicationController

  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  respond_to :json

  def show
    @harvest_schedule = HarvestSchedule.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @harvest_schedule
  end    
end
```

and the spec:

```
let(:schedule) { mock_model(HarvestSchedule).as_null_object }

describe "GET show" do
   before(:each) do
     HarvestSchedule.stub(:find).with("1") { schedule }
   end

   it "finds the harvest schedule" do
     HarvestSchedule.should_receive(:find).with("1") { schedule }
     get :show, id: 1
     assigns(:harvest_schedule).should eq schedule
   end
end
```

When I run the spec, the error is:

```
Failure/Error: HarvestSchedule.should_receive(:find).with("1") { schedule }
ActionController::UnknownFormat:
  ActionController::UnknownFormat
# ./app/controllers/harvest_schedules_controller.rb:29:in `show'
# ./spec/controllers/harvest_schedules_controller_spec.rb:41:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>'
```

I cannot see any problem in the controller or spec at all. The app was using Rails 3.2.12 before and all the specs passed. This error only occurs after I upgraded Rails version to 4.1.4. I am using rspec 2.14.1. Did anyone encounter similar problem?

Cheers

Answer (score 3):

You've specified that the action only responds to requests for JSON here:

```
respond_to :json
```

So, you need to request a JSON response in your spec as well:

```
get :show, id: 1, format: 'json'
```

Comment: Hi @infused, I tried it but new error is `undefined method `authenticate' for nil:NilClass`. I wonder if it's Rails 4 issue

Comment: i think you may also need to add `params: { id: 1 }`